# VS Code not tracking file changes and says install git

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

extension: GitHub Pull Requests and Issues
Don't know why its behaving like this, git is installed... still its saying install git

showing:
`Activating the Pull Requests and Issues extension failed. Please make sure you have git installed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to setting and search `git path`

edit the `setting.json` in there, the last parameter git.path

[image]

find the git path with this command in terminal

`which git`

then reload the VS Code